# New Update on Google Play

Tags: android, apk

I just uploaded a new version for my app on Google Play. How long does it take for Google Play to notify users of the updated? Or do I have to physically do it myself?

Comment: For me it takes anything between 2-3 hrs.

Comment: What would be the procedure to do it 'physically'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's vary device by device. Some device takes 2 to 4 hrs and some device takes more than 1 days also.

It's tough to tell you exact time.